# I cannot change the word in database using jQuery and php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am making a simple dictionary that allows user to edit or update word, part of speech and definition. The part of speech and definition can be edited but the logical error here is that I cannot edit the word. So how do I edit a searched word? In navicat, my sql query UPDATE works well in editing a word but it doesn't work in the jQuery side.

here's my query using navicat. In here updating of word works we'll but it doesn't work in php and jQuery

```
UPDATE english SET eng_word="boy", pos='noun', definition="boy meaning" WHERE eng_word="girl";
```

here's my code for editing in php

```
<?php
//$q1=$_GET["q1"];
//$q2=$_GET["q2"];
//$q3=$_GET["q3"];
$q1=$_POST["q1"];

$q_dit=$_POST["$q_dit"]; //use to edit the word but it's not working

$q2=$_POST["q2"];
$q3=$_POST["q3"];

$con = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
if (!$con)
 {
 die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
 }

mysql_select_db("dictionary_ajax", $con);

    //$sql="UPDATE stud_info SET LName='$q2', FName='$q3' WHERE IDno='$q1'";

//my query for update and edit

    $sql="UPDATE english SET eng_word='$q_dit', pos='$q2', definition='$q3' WHERE eng_word='$q1'"; 

if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
  }


mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Code for jQuery that helps edit the database

```
$("#Edit").click(function() {

    var x1 = $("#Word").val();

    var e = $("#Word1").val(); //use to edit the word but still not working

    var x2 = $("#pos").val();
    var x3 = $("#def").val();
    $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "editStud.php",
            data: {q1: x1, q2: x2, q3: x3, q_dit: e}, //q_dit: e not working I can't edit the word
            success: function(html){
                    $(".View").click();
            }
        });
    return false;
});
```

HTML for inputs

```
    <form>
            <div>
                Word  
                <input type="text" id="Word">
            </div>

            <div>
                Edit_word   
                <input type="text" id="Word1">
            </div>

            <div>
                Pos 
                <input type="text" id="pos">
            </div>
            <div>
                def 
                <input type="text" id="def">
            </div>
            <center>
                <input id="Edit" type="button" value="Edit">      
            </center>
</form>
```

Comment: jQuery ajax > replace type: 'POST' with method: 'POST' or use $.post for easier syntax

Comment: @user3808774 from what I can see in your code you have $q_dit=$_POST["$q_dit"]; 
You need to remove the $ from your post request to look like this $_POST['q_dit'];

Comment: oh I see, I've never noticed that

Answer (score 1):

On this line:

```
 $sql="UPDATE english SET eng_word='$q_dit', pos='$q2', definition='$q3'
```

You aren't sending the contents of the variables, just the string of the variable name. Try:

```
$sql="UPDATE english SET eng_word=`" . $q_dit . "`, pos=`" . $q2. "`, definition=`" . $q3 . "` WHERE eng_word=`" . $q1 . "`";
```

Comment: Not sure I follow what you mean.

Comment: Firstly, as the query string is encapsulated in double quotes, the **value** of the variable is sent. Secondly, why have you put backticks around the values? They're only really supposed to be used for table and column identifiers, not the values.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/0z08m8hdfmuwowv/edit_word.PNG?dl=0 please take a look at the GUI. I just can't edit the word and that's the only problem.